# dynamically disable animation highcharts javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, highcharts, uicollectionviewcell

I am building an app which uses a highcharts graph embedded inside a webview. 
This webview is a collectionViewCell and therefore is reloaded when scrolled. 
I would like to set an attribute to disable animation so that the graphs dont reanimate everytime they are forced to reload during scrolls

I would like to do something like this

```
if (notNew) {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#container').highcharts().setOptions({plotOptions:{series:{animation:'false'}}});"];
}
```

but it isnt working 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can only disable animations in this way: 
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.animation